# Finding memory allocation error

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, allocation

I'm getting memory allocation errors (and a subsequent crash) on the following simplified code:

```
std::wstring myKey = L"str_not_actually_constant";

MyType obj;
Read( obj );

std::map<std::wstring, MyType> myMap;
myMap[myKey] = obj; // Sometimes allocation error (1)
...
Read( MyType& obj )
{
  obj.member1 = ReadFromFuncThatMayBeProblem();
  obj.member2 = ReadFromFuncThatMayBeProblem(); // Sometimes allocation error (2)
  /* more members */
}
...
void operator =( const MyType& source )
{
  if( this != &source )
  {
    member1 = source.member1; // std::wstring
    member2 = source.member2; // Usually (1) happen on the second member. // std::wstring
    /* more members */
  }
}
```

Either (1) or (2) occur.

Now, if I simply continue on regardless of the error (with the debugger), the value is indeed entered in the map.

I don't know if ReadFromFuncThatMayBeProblem() is the culprit but it's a fairly complex function that I cannot devulge here.

Also, this is code that has worked (or at least appeared to work) before other sections of the application was ported to use OpenSSL. I don't know if that may have had any effect here, though.

So, what can I do to track down this allocation error, since I'm presuming that the above code is not in fact the problem?

Edit: More info:
There is no dtor for MyType.

However, MyType has a member of type SecondType that has a void* member. This is being deleted and null'd in that type's destructor. The constructor uses m_pData = new std::wstring( *( (std::wstring* )source.m_pData) ); for strings. (And similar for other data types). Could that be an issue? (delete static_cast< std::wstring* >( m_pData );)

The other member types of MyType are std::wstring, unsigned long, bool, enum, structs (timeb among them) and SecondType.

Comment: Do you have a complete test case, one we could try out?

Comment: Does MyType contains any pointer member variables? in that case, copy ctor and assignment operator written properly?

Comment: outis: No, sorry. I can't provide that.
Naveen: There's no pointer member variables.

Comment: If you found it necessary to provide an assignment op, you will almostv certainly need to provide  a copy ctor and a dtor. You need to show the code for them. But I suspect you have corrupted the heap somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You need to post the real code. And there is almost no reason to ever use void * in C++.

Comment: Seems SO formats things weirdly ^^

Comment: Niel: I can't post the real code.

Comment: @Fredrik: how about equivalent code, code that's complete and exhibits the problematic behavior (i.e. a minimal test case)? That's what we really need.

Comment: outis: Yeah, I know. I'm trying to do that for myself, too. :) I've been able to track down somewhat what's causing it -- there's a problem with our handling of long longs.

Comment: I believe this is not a real question unless you put in the buggy (part of the) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally tracked down the error.

We are using the above functionality as part of a larger socket communication using OpenSSL (hence above reference). The socket was writing data and reading data as per above code simplification.

The way the socket was read was that we were re-allocating memory from one buffer to another (changing size dynamically). While doing this, we use the input of the buffer and the size we should expand with. The size calculation was using modulo to calculate the factor of the re-size. This caused the buffer to either be too large or too small to fit the following operations.

Two days of debugging to change a '%' to a '/'.

Thanks for all support, though.

Comment: I've a feeling you do not use assertions or much of logging. How do you plan to keep the code beast under your leash?

Comment: We are using assertions and logging. We simply didn't have anything like that in this case or in this particular part.   It feels like you're trying to pick a fight...

Comment: +1 for simple error that requires a disproportionate effort to fix. Nice to know programming never changes at its core.

Answer (score 0):

what type does ReadFromFuncThatMayBeProblem() return? Does it return a (const) reference? if so, is the object still valid after leaving the scope of ReadFromFuncThatMayBeProblem()?

Comment: It returns whatever the type the member is (std::wstring, long etc). (Non-const.)